# What is the differences between Tkinter, WxWidgets and PyQt, and PySide?

Tags: tkinter, pyqt, comparison, wxpython, pyside

I was wondering what are the differences among the GUI toolkits such as tkinter, wxWidgets and PyQt, PySide. They produces similar widgets like list boxes, text engines, and buttons, check boxes, etc. I was confused by the similar engines there.

I am using Tkinter right now, and I found that it’s lacking of complex widgets, like the using of table. I have tried to use the tree view before, but I found out that there’s a widget called QTable something in PyQt and PySide.

I was confused by those names and different usages, especially I cannot distinguish PyQt and Pyside.

Oh, furthermore, I was using Python 3.9 and running on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: PySide and PyQt are both wrappers for the C++ Qt framework.  Their are some subtle differences but they are largely very similar.

Comment: OK, I got it. I will try to use them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First thing first, there are actually ***no*** *pure* Python GUI toolkit in the Python language. All of the mentioned toolkits are **bindings**. Let me talk about why.

### Tkinter

Tkinter, from Python version 2 or earlier, is the *only* *standard* GUI (Graphical User Interface) library in the Python programming language. It is a GUI toolkit that it needs not to install via `pip` or `conda` or some package manager, in Python (however, if you want to get some good or call directly to the `Tcl`, you may install it from `apt get` or https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/, etc.). Its the wrapper of the `Tk` GUI toolkit, inside the `Tcl` language.

Two of the GUI package available in the `PyPI` as I have known so far, which are the `PySimplyGUI` and `CustomTkinter` is based on tkinter, but not developing a GUI library from scratch.

While Tkinter was complained about its old-styled interface and buggy old- and slow-updating, it still has the following advantages to "survive" in the GUI developing world:

- Tkinter is a direct, *standard* library for the Python language. That means no installation is required and that's a *huge* convenience to the enthusiast programmers and coding kids who haven't set up the `$PATH` correctly or doesn't know how to use `pip` or `conda` or `PyQt5` or something else.
- Secondly, Tkinter is complained about its old-styled interface. In fact, as you might know (because you claims that you're a Tkinter user), there's some module called `ttk` and its the renew version of the `tk.widgets`. That's improving its styling configuration and add few new and modern widgets inside it (for example, `ttk.Notebook`, `ttk.ComboBox`, etc.)
- Thirdly, Tkinter is well-known for its simplicity and the ease of learning it. The learning graph of Tkinter is ***not*** steep, and its straightforward so that you can handle it very fast.

### wxWidgets

wxWidgets is a GUI toolkit that wraps the `C` or `C++` GUI framework. It contains numeral advanced widgets such as printing dialogs and font dialogs (however, in Tkinter 8.7 it starts supporting the native `font dialog`.)

One of the shining point of wxWidgets is its GUI designer, as known as the `WxFormBuilder` as well as `WxWidgets GUI Designer`.

### Qt

> GUI toolkit such as Tkinter, ... PyQt and PySide

Starting from 1995, Qt become the biggest market for the ***application** development framework* and has the largest range and wide of user (developer).

Oh yeah, one thing I want to correct you. As a Qt user, I want to talk about that Qt is not just a GUI toolkit, although the most famous part of Qt is its GUI building. Qt is an application development framework. In here, you'll probably need no modules but Qt to develop an app, even a super-app. Not only GUI and its builder, `Qt Creator`, but Qt supports large range of application development stuff. It supports web engine, text editor, backend threading, XML processing and even PDF processing or Image converting using `QImage`, `QPixmap` or `<QtOpenGL>. You can integrate the Qt with other modules such as` OpenCV` also.

Both PyQt and PySide are the Python binding of the C++ Qt. Both of them are base on a source code called `qtbase`. However, here's the differences, refer to https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pyqt5-vs-pyside2/:

- PyQt uses the *General Public License version 2* (GPL2), or a commercial license if you want to use PyQt in commercial activities and publish it to the public. On the other hand, PySide uses the *Lesser General Public License version 3.0* (LGPL3).
- When you calling to `QApplication`, PyQt5 or PyQt6 must fill in a list of string, usually `sys.argv`. However, PySide does not *require* user to do so.
- PyQt uses `PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal` and `pyqtSlot`. However, PySide uses `PySide2.QtCore.Signal` and `Slot`. But there attributes and initializing method, as well as the decorators are kept the same.
- Overall PyQt and PySide are 99.999% similar.

### Examples

It seems that there's no table control in the Tkinter framework, neither `Tcl/Tk` nor `Python tkinter`.

Regard to your example, its a code written in `Qt`, in both `C++` and `Python`.

Our result:

[image: rst]

##### Using C++ Qt

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTableWidget>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    public:
        MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
            : QMainWindow(parent)
        {
            m_tableWidget = new QTableWidget(this);
            m_tableWidget->setRowCount(10);
            m_tableWidget->setColumnCount(5);
            setCentralWidget(m_tableWidget);
        }

    private:
        QTableWidget* m_tableWidget;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

##### Using Python PyQt/PySide (actually you can replace everything but changing the PyQt5 to PySide2

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.__table_widget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.__table_widget.setRowCount(10)
        self.__table_widget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__table_widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: "if you want to use PyQt in commercial activities" That's not correct: you can still use PyQt for commercial software without paying the license, *as long* as you also make the code available.

Answer (score 1):

PyQt and PySide are both binding to the Qt library (the differences are pointed here : https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pyqt5-vs-pyside2/).

Tkinter (Tk interface) is a binding to an other library, Tk, designed initially for the Tcl language. As you have pointed it is a lighter library. And the look and feel differs from the native widgets.

wxWidgets is an other library. Its page compare it to Qt and other such libraries https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits One point is wxWidgets uses native widgets (those from Windows on Windows…) and Qt uses self designed widgets (but they emulate the look and feel of the system)

These 3 widget sets are quite portable and will works on Windows, Mac, Linux.